My game wont acknowledge my animator and is giving me no errors
In unity when I have it made so when my camera collider interacts with an object I get the option and ability to interact with it. I already set up the animator and put a trigger called press. When I activate the trigger manually from the unity animator everything works fine
but
when I try to press E Either the entire thing breaks and tries to animate something else entirely and I can see it does not refer to the animator I set up because the transitions are not shining.
I am trying to move just the toilet lid thats what I left the other children static because it would glitch out and move the entire toilet.
Currently when I trigger the "press" manually from unity it does everything I want it to do and the transitions are right. Only when I
try to press E that it does not work
An image showing my objects parent
The animator that has proper transitions and the trigger that activates them
THe inspector of my actual object
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class pooplol : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator Toilet;
    public AudioSource kmms;
    public GameObject inttext;

    private bool isInteractable = false;

    void Start()
    {
        // Try to fetch the Animator component
        Toilet = GetComponent<Animator>();
        if (Toilet == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Animator component not found on the GameObject to which this script is attached.");
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isInteractable && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            Debug.Log("E key pressed and interactable is true.");
            Toilet.ResetTrigger("press");
            Toilet.SetTrigger("press");
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("MainCamera"))
        {
            inttext.SetActive(true);
            isInteractable = true;
            Debug.Log("MainCamera is within trigger area.");
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("MainCamera"))
        {
            inttext.SetActive(false);
            isInteractable = false;
            Debug.Log("MainCamera has exited the trigger area.");
        }
    }
}


Please add your code directly to the question as text.

ok done added my code

the animator will animate what its on.. so, i guess you need to share these errors and the setup of where your animator is, and technically this script should be with it so show they are both there on the same object

I added the photos of the parent, the actual object, and the animtor
